# Incorrect MIME type when reverse proxying nodejs app with nginx using regex in location

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm self-hosting a [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) site with [jekyll-admin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin) for editing.

jekyll-admin adds a nodejs based admin panel. I want to be able to access this over the internet via a nginx reverse-proxy.

- jekyll 4.0.0
- jekyll-admin 0.9.6
- node 10.16.3
- nginx 1.17.4

This configuration works :

```
server {
     listen 80;

     server_name www.example.com;
     root /home/foo/_site;

     location ^~ /admin {
         auth_basic "Administration";
         auth_basic_user_file /foo/htpasswd;

         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin;

         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     }

     location ^~ /_api {
         auth_basic "Administration";
         auth_basic_user_file /foo/htpasswd;

         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/_api;

         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     }

     # caching for static site

     location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
       expires 1M;
       add_header Cache-Control "public";
     }

     location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
       expires 1h;
       add_header Cache-Control "public";
     }
 }
```

However I want to remove the duplication so I merge the two location blocks for the proxy and use a regex:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;

     server_name www.example.com;
     root /home/foo/_site;

     location ~ ^/(admin|_api)(/.*)? {
          auth_basic_user_file /foo/htpasswd;
          auth_basic "Administration";

          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000$1;

          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     }
}
```

But my site no longer works - I now get a blank page and the browser error console shows

> The resource from “http://www.example.com/admin/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>   admin
>
> The resource from “http://www.example.com/admin/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>   admin
>
> Loading failed for the  with source “http://www.example.com/admin/bundle.js”. admin:11:1

What is causing the js and css content to get the wrong MIME type here?

The nginx logs show nothing unusual.

Comment: This is not a proper answer, but look very carefully at the effective permissions for nginx to read those files following your change. I had this problem when the files became non-readable to nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dumb error in `proxy_pass`

```
   location ~ ^/(admin|_api)(/.*)? {
      ...
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/$1$2;
    }
```